# iPhone, Need to check if values have changed before I update my database?

Tags: iphone

I've gone for a simple approach, I've created some NSString variables which I set when the view load...

```
strKeptDesc = txtDescription.text;

NSLog(@"KDesc  =#%@# CDesc  =#%@#",strKeptDesc, txtDescription.text);
```

Which works as excepted and output the values you'd expect.

However in my db commit function, when I check the variables I get errors...

```
NSMethodSignature: 0x5c3fa80># CDesc  =#Gas bill3#
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

In my h file I have

```
NSString *strKeptDesc;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strKeptDesc;
```

I synthesize too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strKeptDesc = txtDescription.text;
```

in this line you simply assign a string value to your iVar and your accessor methods do not get called - so if you're assigning autoreleased string it may be released and become invalid. You must write

```
self.strKeptDesc = txtDescription.text;
```

instead, so strKeptDesc will be retained in setter and remain valid outside the current method.